# How to make "/" commands in javascript for html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

So I want to be able to type in commands for a dice rolling mechanic similar to roll20 like "/r 2d20". It would "roll" 2 D 20's and list the results. I'm having trouble finding a way to do this. Any advice, tips, or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Look into using `.substring()` or `.substr()` and `.chatAt()` on the users input to get the components of the user's command, and then perform required actions

Comment: @JBDouble05 I haven't really tried any code yet. I've just been researching.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression and capture the groups of your string. Here is an example:

```
var s = '/r 2d20';
var m = s.match(/\/r\s+(\d+)(\w)(\d+)/);
console.log(m[1]);
console.log(m[2]);
console.log(m[3]);
```

This code prints:

```
2
d
20
```

Comment: This looks great bug can you explain to me a little bit how it works?

Comment: @Giles My solution uses a regular expression, which is a pattern that will be applied to the string. It basically contains three groups: `(\d+)(\w)(\d+)`. The `(\d+)` part matches one or more digits; The `(\w)` part matches a character. This pattern can then be used to extract the pieces of the string by calling the `match` method, which returns the matched groups in an array. Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions